# animation on canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I am working on application in which i am drawing a image on the canvas now i want o draw the second image in that canvas. 
for example see the image ......
[image]

the first image s looking as follow ....
when i click on some place then it will show as follow 
but the other thing which is shown in the image (thymin) it should display as fadein in the canvas
[image]
how to do it i am not getting any thing can any one help me .....

Answer (score 0):

That's quite complicated by the sounds of it though not impossible to achieve. I think it would take more than the standard [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class to achieve this, more like you would need to use the [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) class where you have greater control over what gets drawn and where and when. If you're not familiar with Android 2D graphics then a good place to start would be [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html).

Comment: SurfaceView is what you need then. You can do such intricate things like that.

Answer (score 0):

For drawing the bitmap, you could use canvasObject.drawBitmap() method of [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class. drawBitmap takes a paint object as one of its parameters, you could programmatically vary the alpha value of the paint object to create a fade-in effect. [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) class has a setAlpha(value) method to do this. I haven't tried this out myself but this should work.